# Use an array to call a constructor with varargs

Tags: java, reflection

Assuming you have a string with the name of a class you want to instantiate and additionally you have an string which contains comma separated the parameters of the constructor. You can assume that the constructor takes only Strings as parameters or varargs of String. You do NOT know before what classes will be used you can only inspect them using reflection.

Example:

```
String clazzName = "com.example.Sample";
String parameters = "Apple,Cow,Red"

// can be used to instantiate this class

public class Sample {
    public Sample(String fruit, String animal, String color) { }
}
```

I wrote an algorithm for doing this using the following logic:

1. Split the string into an array `parameterArray` (in the example: `parameterArray=["Apple", "Cow", "Red"]`)
2. Construct an array `clazzArray` of type `Class<?>[]` which contains `String.class` n times where ne is the length of `parameterArray` (in the example: `clazzArray=[String.class, String.class, String.class]`)
3. Search for a constructor using reflection and invoke it: `Class.forName(clazzName).getConstructor(clazzArray).newInstance(parameterArray);`

This works fine, now assume that you have an class which accepts varargs for one of the parameters:

```
String clazzName = "com.example.VASample";
String parameters = "Party Host,Guest 1,Guest2,Guest3"

// can be used to instantiate this class

public class VASample {
    public VASample(String host, String... guests) { }
}
```

Now `parameterArray` is an 3 element array and I (of course do not find a constructor). I know that I could get that constructor if I searched for a `[String, String[]]` constructor on the class. **But how can you know before?**

I'm searching for an code-snippet/algorithm/library that finds a constructor for a provided array of parameters paying attention to varargs. So providing it with a `[String, String, String]` array, it will match either a `[String, String, String]` constructor, a `[String[]]` constructor (varargs only) or a `[String, String[]]` Constructor (arg+varargs).

I know that the java-compile (of course) handles this internally when parsing java source, but how can I emulate something similar using reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can implement the rules similar to Java, you need to recall the rules:

1. If there is an exact match, read a matching method without varargs, that method is preferred
2. If there is no exact match but multiple matching varargs methods, e.g. `(String,String...)` and `(String,String,String...)` when you look for `(String,String,String)`, the lookup fails with an “ambiguous method” error

So you can implement the complete lookup by first trying a direct lookup to find an exact match and only if that fails, iterate over all candidates, failing if you find more than one.

The following code does this. It’s simplified compared to the Java language rules as it assumes, like you said in your question, that only `String` parameters match so no widening conversions are considered.

```
static Object lookup(String clazzName, String parameters)
                                               throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    String[] args=parameters.split(",");
    int nArg=args.length;
    Class<?>[] argType=new Class<?>[nArg];
    Arrays.fill(argType, String.class);

    Class<?> clazz=Class.forName(clazzName);
    Lookup l=MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle handle;
    try {
        // if there is an exact match (without varargs), Java prefers that
        handle=l.findConstructor(clazz, MethodType.methodType(void.class, argType));
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        // we have to search all candidates, like Java we reject ambiguous methods
        Constructor<?> found=null;
        find: for(Constructor<?> c: clazz.getConstructors()) {
            if(!c.isVarArgs()) continue;
            Class<?>[] param = c.getParameterTypes();
            int nConcrete = param.length-1;
            if(nConcrete>nArg || param[nConcrete]!=String[].class) continue find;
            for(int ix=0; ix<nConcrete; ix++)
                if(param[ix]!=String.class) continue find;
            if(found!=null) throw new NoSuchMethodException(
                                             "ambiguous: "+found+" and "+c+" match");
            found=c;
        }
        handle=l.unreflectConstructor(found);
    }
    try {
        return handle.invokeWithArguments((Object[])args);
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
        throw new InvocationTargetException(ex);
    }
}
```

This uses a combination of the newer invocation API (`MethodHandle`s) and the old Reflection. The advantage is that the former already supports the varargs processing of the arguments on the invocation side (the conversion of our flat argument array to a combination of concrete parameters and an array holding the remaining elements).

But it doesn’t support iterating over all constructors so for that lookup part we have to fall back to the old Reflection API (`Class.getConstructors()`).

Comment: Thanks for that code, where did you get that from? Or did you just write that?

Comment: I just wrote that to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [java.lang.reflect.Constructor#isVarArgs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#isVarArgs--) to see if the constructor was defined with varags or not.

You can iterate over the list of constructors for your class using `YourClass.class.getConstructors()` and then check which one has the been declared with varargs.